# Wordpress Multisite - get blog description and header image

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have multiste install and I need to pull sub blog title, url, description and header image to main site.

I do get blog id numbers. I can get blog title and url but unable to get description and header image.

```
    <?php foreach ( $blogs as $blog ):

        $description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
        ?>

        <?php
        $blog_details = get_blog_details( $blog );
        echo 'Blog ' . $blog_details->blog_id . ' nimi ' . $blog_details->blogname . '.';
        echo $blog_details->siteurl;
        ?>

        <div class="blog_description">
            <?php echo $description; ?>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Description is from main site, not from sub blog. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the `switch_to_blog( $blog );`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog

This solves my problem.